# How to find the past 4 weeks of the same weekday value starting today

Tags: sql-server, date

I am trying to select records from today and the same day of each week for the last 4 weeks.

1. Today (Tuesday)
2. Last Tuesday
3. The Tuesday before that
4. The Tuesday before that

I need this to be tied to current date because I am going to run this query every day so I don't want to use a between or something where I manually specify the date range.

Everything I have found or tried so far has pulled the last month of data but not the last 4 weeks of the same weekday.

```
select *
from table
where thedatecolumn >= DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE())
```

This works but pulls everything from the last month.

If today's date is `7/10/2019` I need

```
Data from 7/10/2019
Data from 7/3/2019
Data from 6/26/2019
Data from 6/19/2019
```

Every day I will run this query, so I need it to be dynamic based on the current date.

Comment: *"Today (Tuesday)"* Today is Wednesday/Thursday (depending where you are geographically, but no where is UTC -21 for it to be Tuesday), so are you always after Tuesday's data, regardless of the day it actually is?

Comment: Get midnight of today, then use BETWEEN midnight AND {midnight + 23h59m59s}. Add BETWEEN {midnight-7d} AND {midnight-7d + 23h59m59s}. And so on for the remaining weeks.

Comment: @ŁukaszNojek - there are values outside that range due to the values less than a second.  You need given date >= and < for a given date + 1 with no time like '2019-12-03 00:00:00.000' and that date + 1.

Comment: True, it was just a simplification in limited space of comment. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to look back 21 days and then filter those dates that have the same day of week:

```
select * from table
where thedatecolumn >= DATEADD(DAY, -21, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
    and DATEPART(WEEKDAY, thedatecolumn) = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())
```

Comment: @data_stephen I edited my answer after I realized that you only want data for the four dates falling on the same day of week.

Comment: This is great and simple. Thank you very much!

Comment: As far as I know, using functions on columns prevents you from using indices. You may observe low performance of this query for big tables. It's better to avoid such solutions when performance is relevant.

Comment: @Lukasz I believe you'll find the lower bound on 21 days to be completely sargable.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try using a recursive cte which starts today and repeatedly substracts 7 days - so you ensure you always land on the same weekday. Following an example:

```
WITH cteFromToday AS(
 SELECT 0 AS WeeksBack, GETDATE() AS MyDate
 UNION ALL
 SELECT WeeksBack + 1 AS WeeksBack, DATEADD(d, -7, MyDate) AS MyDate
   FROM cteFromToday
)
SELECT TOP 5 *
  FROM cteFromToday
  OPTION ( MaxRecursion 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple.  Substitute `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` here for any given date.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS Today, 
DATEADD(DAY,-7,CONVERT(DATE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) AS LastWeek ,
DATEADD(DAY,-14,CONVERT(DATE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) AS TwoWeeksAgo, 
DATEADD(DAY,-21,CONVERT(DATE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) AS ThreeWeeksAgo
```

SO, if you want to get data for a set of ranges for one entire day with those dates:

```
SELECT something
WHERE
datetimecolumn >= CONVERT(DATE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND datetimecolumn < DATEADD(DAY,1, CONVERT(DATE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) -- Todays range, 
OR datetimecolumn >= DATEADD(DAY,-7,CONVERT(DATE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) AND datetimecolumn < DATEADD(DAY,1,DATEADD(DAY,-7,CONVERT(DATE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)))-- LastWeek ,
OR datetimecolumn >= DATEADD(DAY,-14,CONVERT(DATE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) AND datetimecolumn < DATEADD(DAY,1,DATEADD(DAY,-14,CONVERT(DATE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)))-- TwoWeeksAgo, 
OR datetimecolumn >= DATEADD(DAY,-21,CONVERT(DATE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) AND datetimecolumn < DATEADD(DAY,1, DATEADD(DAY,-21,CONVERT(DATE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))) -- ThreeWeeksAgo
```

Comment: Mark, thank you very much. This returns the exact same results at shawnt00 but since I am including this in a larger query I still may need 2 options on how to do it. Much appreciated.